# Rerender списка по клику на кнопку

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Использую пакеты react-window, react-virtualized-auto-sizer, react-window-infinite-loader: по нажатию на кнопку "Сортировать по убыванию/возрастанию" хочу сделать rerender всего списка(и чтобы скролл был установлен на начальную позицию). Сейчас после нажатия на кнопку ничего не меняется, но после того как начинаем скроллить, новые запросы уже приходят как нужно

https://codesandbox.io/s/large-data-sort-74ll6?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Я не знаю реакт но похоже что по клику должен вызываться какой то метод который будет подгружать данные. Какой то fetch. Можно для запроса данных использовать axios. Для установки скрола можно использовать что то типа этого - window.scrollTo(x-coord, y-coord);

Answer (score 0):

нашел в документации react-window-infinite-loader, кажется это именно ваша проблема:

"Some use cases require cached items to be reset. For example, after a list has been sorted, previously cached items may be invalid. You can let InfiniteLoader know that it needs to reload cached items by calling the resetloadMoreItemsCache method."

```
function ExampleWrapper({
  // ...
  sortOrder,
}) {
  // We create a reference for the InfiniteLoader
  const infiniteLoaderRef = useRef(null);
  const hasMountedRef = useRef(false);

  // Each time the sort prop changed we called the method resetloadMoreItemsCache to clear the cache
  useEffect(() => {
    // We only need to reset cached items when "sortOrder" changes.
    // This effect will run on mount too; there's no need to reset in that case.
    if (hasMountedRef.current) {
      if (infiniteLoaderRef.current) {
        infiniteLoaderRef.current.resetloadMoreItemsCache();
      }
    }
    hasMountedRef.current = true;
  }, [sortOrder]);
  
  // ...

  // We passed down the ref to the InfiniteLoader component
  return (
    <InfiniteLoader
      ref={infiniteLoaderRef}
      isItemLoaded={isItemLoaded}
      itemCount={itemCount}
      loadMoreItems={loadMoreItems}
    >
      {({ onItemsRendered, ref }) => (
        // ...
      )}
    </InfiniteLoader>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/embed/lucid-tree-7wnrq